# Is it possible to make my discord.js bot ignore certain users? More like adding them to a json file by a command and ignoring all of them

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make my bot ignore **certain** users while executing commands?

I have no code to show as I don't know where to start and haven't found anything after searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of **user ids** who are blacklisted from executing commands, you can simply do the following:

```
const arrayOfUsersIds = ['8794328794879328794897', '789438729489732789', '764327969748632978'];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfUsersIds.length; i++) {
    if (message.author.id === arrayOfUsersIds[i]) return message.reply('You are on the blacklist!');
};
```

Simply add all **user ids** in this array named `arrayOfUsersIds` and all this users are not allowed to execute commands anymore.

---

**You can do the same with usernames!** Simply add all names of users in the array named `arrayOfUsersnames` that you don't want to execute commands in the array and then they aren't allowed to execute commands anymore!

```
const arrayOfUsersNames = ['Monkeyyy11', 'Tden', 'Zenoo'];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfUsersNames.length; i++) {
    if (message.author.username.toLowerCase() === arrayOfUsersNames[i].toLowerCase()) return message.reply('You are on the blacklist!');
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a command that adds IDs and Tags to the array?

Comment: That's the problem, i'm not really good with these stuff so i was hoping that you could teach me, if possible.

Comment: Uhh that's too broad sorry. I can't choose a database for you. You should at least give it a try and when you need help, you can come back! :) But normally my answer should have answered your question so it would be nice if you mark it as correct. @mexuzu